# How to set "File Roller" (aka File Manager) as default for ALL supported types in Gnome and Cinnamon?

Tags: linux, gnome, file-association, cinnamon, mime-types

Ever since I installed [`p7zip-gui`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/p7zip-gui), it hijacked my system by setting itself as default application for all mime types it can open (31 types in total).

Cinnamon provides a tool called Preferred Applications, but there's no "compressed/archives" grouping:

[image]

How to revert to having File Roller open all supported types *by default*, while still keeping the possibility to open them with p7zip-gui?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a complement to the previous answer by [theJack](https://superuser.com/users/578703/thejack).

In order to accomplish my goal, I had to:

1. open the file `/usr/share/applications/Archive Manager` (actually named `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop` if listed from the command line, for example) in a text editor
2. copy everything directly after `MimeType=`
3. replace every semicolon by a space using a text editor with "Search and Replace"
4. input the resulting string as a parameter to `xdg-mime`. From the manual: "*An application can be made the default for several file types by specifying multiple mimetypes.*"

The resulting command:

```
xdg-mime default "org.gnome.FileRoller.desktop" application/x-7z-compressed application/x-7z-compressed-tar application/x-ace application/x-alz application/x-ar application/x-arj application/x-bzip application/x-bzip-compressed-tar application/x-bzip1 application/x-bzip1-compressed-tar application/x-cabinet application/x-cd-image application/x-compress application/x-compressed-tar application/x-cpio application/x-deb application/x-ear application/x-ms-dos-executable application/x-gtar application/x-gzip application/x-gzpostscript application/x-java-archive application/x-lha application/x-lhz application/x-lrzip application/x-lrzip-compressed-tar application/x-lz4 application/x-lzip application/x-lzip-compressed-tar application/x-lzma application/x-lzma-compressed-tar application/x-lzop application/x-lz4-compressed-tar application/x-lzop-compressed-tar application/x-ms-wim application/x-rar application/x-rar-compressed application/x-rpm application/x-source-rpm application/x-rzip application/x-rzip-compressed-tar application/x-tar application/x-tarz application/x-stuffit application/x-war application/x-xz application/x-xz-compressed-tar application/x-zip application/x-zip-compressed application/x-zoo application/zip application/x-archive application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed application/vnd.debian.binary-package application/gzip
```

Comment: It does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit mime type associations using the [`xdg-mime`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-mime) command.

All you need to do is find out the name of the .desktop file for File Roller, then enter the command `xdg-mime default program.desktop compressed/archives`, replacing `program.desktop` with the name of the actual file, of course.  This also works with wildcards, so if you wanted to set it to open, say, all compressed files, you could specify `compressed/*`.

Comment: [edited into an answer] feel free to incorporate my answer in yours if you want me to accept it, and let me know if you do. Thanks.